# how to Send html email with dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

```
const doc = [{id: 2, title: 'hello word', email: 'test@email.com'},{id: 3, title: 'post data'}, email: 'test@email.com'}]

 {
                    doc.map(data => {
                        var readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
                            fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
                                if (err) {
                                    throw err;
                                    callback(err);
                                }
                                else {
                                    callback(null, html);
                                }
                            });
                        };

                        readHTMLFile(__dirname + '/../emailTemplates/newsletter.html', function (err, html) {
                            var template = handlebars.compile(html);
                            var replacements = {
                                name: data.name
                            };
                            var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
                            var mailOptions = {
                                from: 'info@fnmotivation.com',
                                to: data.email,
                                subject: 'Check out story posts in your communities',
                                html: htmlToSend
                            };
                            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    callback(err);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    })
                }
```

I want to mail only once the data stored in doc variable but the mail is sent twice probably because I used map the doc variable. Any Idea how to send in one mail?

Comment: because you've put `transporter.sendMail` inside map and will be called for each entry.

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you correct the code and paste it here?

Comment: can you name the transporter library?

Comment: I am using aws.SES

Comment: I can't see `sendMail()` method in docs.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html

Comment: let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// configure AWS SDK
const path = require('path')
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '../config/config.json')

aws.config.loadFromPath(dirPath)

// create Nodemailer SES transporter
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: new aws.SES({
        apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
    })
});

Comment: I used this method

Comment: okay, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `doc.map` method and get `toEmailAddresses` as comma separated string from the doc list.

```
const doc = [{ id: 2, title: 'hello word', email: 'test@email.com' }, { id: 3, title: 'post data', email: 'test@email.com' }]

const readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
  fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
      callback(err);
    }
    else {
      callback(null, html);
    }
  });
};

readHTMLFile(__dirname + '/../emailTemplates/newsletter.html', function (err, html) {
  const template = handlebars.compile(html);
  const toEmailAddresses = doc.map(data => data.email).join(); // to get email addresses.

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'info@fnmotivation.com',
    to: toEmailAddresses,
    subject: 'Check out story posts in your communities',
    html: template
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ok I will implement the changes and let you know.